# PHP: is it possible to jump from one case to another inside a switch?

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have a switch where in very rare occasions I might need to jump to another case, I am looking for something like these:

```
switch($var){
 case: 'a'
  if($otherVar != 0){ // Any conditional, it is irrelevant
     //Go to case y;
  }else{
    //case a
  }
 break;
   case 'b':
     //case b code
  break;
   case 'c':
     if($otherVar2 != 0){ // Any conditional, it is irrelevant
        //Go to case y;
     }else{
       //case c
     }
  break;
   .
   .
   .
   case 'x':
     //case x code
  break;
  case 'y':
   //case y code
  break;

  default:
  // more code
  break;
}
```

Is there any GOTO option, I red somewhere about it but can't find it, or maybe another solution? Thanks.

Comment: If you need to use a GOTO you probably don't have something structured right.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need PHP 5.3 or higher, but here:

Here is the **goto** functionality from http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php

```
<?php

$var = 'x';
$otherVar = 1;

switch($var){
    case 'x':
      if($otherVar != 0){ // Any conditional, it is irrelevant
         goto y;
      }else{
        //case X
      }
     break;

    case 'y':
        y:
        echo 'reached Y';
      break;

    default:
      // more code
      break;
}

?>
```

Comment: Great thanks! PHP 5.3 I missed that, I'll have to check my version. Thanks again

Comment: You are most welcome. As others pointed out, this isn't the ideal way to use PHP, but the functionality is obviously there for a reason.

Comment: `goto` is underrated when used _sparingly_ and _very carefully_.  I have used this approach myself on one occasion.  It worked great, so why not!  +1

Answer (score 7):

How about cascading (or not) based on the extra condition?

```
case 'x' :
    if ($otherVar == 0) {
        break;
    }
case 'y' :
```

Comment: That is a good option but if the case I am looking for is not the next one but n after, I would need to add that conditional on each case.

Comment: @EddyXP you didn't illustrate that requirement in your question. Also, can't you just re-order the cases?

Comment: Sure Phil,I guess I needed to give more cases, I added more cases to illustrate it better, thanks a lot.

Comment: nice, but can be prone to errors, in case someone just decided to order the case statements, who knows...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using any tricks in swtich-case, a better logic could be the following.

```
    function func_y() {
     ...
    }

    switch($var){
     case: 'x'
      if($otherVar != 0){ // Any conditional, it is irrelevant
        func_y();
      }else{
        //case X
      }
     break;

      case 'y':
       func_y();
      break;

      default:
      // more code
      break;
    }
```