# PHP numeric casing with goto

Tags: php

I pleasantly found that [it is possible to use goto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237982/php-is-it-possible-to-jump-from-one-case-to-another-inside-a-switch) in PHP:

```
    case 222: return "A"; break;
    case 231: return "B"; break;
    case 234: goto 231;
    case 237: return "C"; break;
    case 251: goto 231;
    case 285: return "D"; break;
```

I have some code like this. There are a lot of keys that shared the same value, so I am trying to use goto to eliminate redundancy. I'm use a switch since it's simpler here than if/else branching.

For various reasons, each case must be explicitly defined as above, even if it just goes to another case. However, running this through a validator, I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''231'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in your code`

I tried surrounding the cases with single quotes, but that still didn't pass. This seems in line with the example above. What am I missing syntax-wise here?

Comment: Just don't use goto in the first place.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: Also, if `return` exists, `break` will make no sense.

Comment: @vivek_23 Yeah, I saw that comic. Unfortunately, there's no other elegant option here. This is a rare case where it's appropriate and logical. I removed the breaks though

Comment: Well, you said _There are a lot of keys that shared the same value_. So you can have an associative array of key value pairs. Switch case won't be needed then.

Comment: @vivek_23 From a maintenance perspective, it won't be as nice. That's why the code is currently in this one line per entry format

Comment: @RiggsFolly Then how does this work?? https://stackoverflow.com/a/19238042/6110631

Comment: @InterLinked From a  maintenance perspective, I think a hard coded key value array would make more sense, as using a switch case, you will have to climb the whole tree of cases to understand what would be exactly returned.

Comment: @vivek_23 It's not that; if one of the values is changed, they would all need to be changed. Sure, I could do a find and replace, but I'm trying to avoid it. A goto also has logical meaning here, because it reflects what's happening in the real world that the code is modeling

Comment: Except that you cannot goto a label (which your example does not have) inside a switch

Comment: Agreed with most of the previous comments, but as a *strict* answer to your question, the labels must follow the same rule as a [variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php#language.variables.basics).

Comment: @Jeto Hmm... so if I prefaced all the cases with a dummy alphabetic character and surrounded in quotes, that would work?

Comment: @InterLinked No, as RiggsFolly pointed out, case labels aren't actually labels you can goto into. You'd have to add a separate label, just like in the answer you linked. But you should seriously consider changing the way things work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label cannot be numeric only, so you could only solve it by creating extra label for `cases` you want to target (and also modifying `gotos` with those new labels):

```
<?php

function foo($value) {
    switch ($value) {
        case 222:
            return "A";
        case 231:
            label231: // new label here
            return "B";
        case 234:
           goto label231;
        case 237:
           return "C";
        case 251: 
           goto label231;
        case 285:
           return "D";
    }
}

var_dump(foo(251));
```

However as mentioned in the comments, I would prefer choosing a different approach (associative array etc.).